# Restify server with Angular, not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, restify

I am learning to use Restify to build a Restful API and work with Angular.

Below is my structure:

```
Project
  page_admin        
    core.js 
    index.html
  node_modules
    restify
    mongojs
  server.js
```

I had set up server and implemented several API calls.

Below news API return a list of JSON data in browser:

```
`http://localhost:8080/news`

`[{"_id":"53b2a2c3373551813dfe8b91","title":"first","subtitle":"foobar","textbody":"","postedOn":"2014-07-01T12:00:03.215Z"},{"_id":"53b2a122373551813dfe8b8e","title":"my second","subtitle":"my second title","textbody":"node is cool","postedOn":"2014-07-01T11:53:06.389Z"},{"_id":"53b2a0cd373551813dfe8b8d","title":"delay announcement","subtitle":"sub ","textbody":"I am the text body","postedOn":"2014-07-01T11:51:41.678Z"}]`
```

here is my code to handle client side route:

```
server.get('/', restify.serveStatic({

    'directory': './page_admin',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));
```

My index.html is simple:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>

<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="bluesky">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>My test app</title>

    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
    <style>
        html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
        body                    { padding-top:50px; }
        #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="core.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>My example is working <span class="label label-info">{{ news.length }}</span></h1>
        </div>

        <!-- TODO LIST -->
        <div id="todo-list" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">

                <!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
                <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="new in news">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(new._id)"> {{ new.subtitle }}
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

core.js is like this:

```
    var bluesky = angular.module('bluesky', []);

    function mainController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.formData = {};

    $http.get('/news')
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.news = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);

        });
    }
```

when I try to navigate to:  `http://localhost:8080`

I got my index page but it shows me:

```
'My example is working {{ news.length }}
```

and in console, I saw following error:

```
    GET `http://localhost:8080/core.js` 404 (Not Found) 
    localhost/:24

    Uncaught Error: No module: bluesky 
    angular.min.js:18
```

what I just missed so that the angular is not retrieving the data?

=============================================================

## upate

if I directly include core.js put code inside , then it works.

but, how to solve this 404 not found issue? just don't want to include all js files in the index page.

Comment: Seems the location for core.js specified in your index file is not correct. Double check the path.

Comment: as it says the it cant find your core.js file

Comment: the files in the page_admin  folder ryt <script src="page_admin/core.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Sam, tried that but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge about angular js, controller is not defined in your module. So instead of using `function mainController($scope, $http) {
....
}`

you should define controller inside the module **bluesky** as follows

`bluesky.controller("mainController",function($scope,$http)
{
....
});`